# How to parse QString?

Tags: c++, qstring

I am trying to parse `QString` with following code:

```
QString name = "name.bin";
QStringList imgName = name.split(".");
qDebug() << imgName.at(0); // result is "name"
```

However I need just **name** without any `(")`. Then I write another code to manually delete quotes("").

Is there any easy way to split `QString`?

Comment: I would use QFileInfo for this instead.

Comment: ***However I need just name without any (")*** There are no embedded quotes in your example. Do you mean your filenames have quotes?

Comment: ***result is "name"*** This is from your debugger. The result is just `name` with no quotes in the actual string.

Comment: I am sorry you are exactly right.. Just because of sitting 11 hours in front of computer..

Answer (score 2):

There are no " " in the string. It just contains Name

```cpp
qDebug() << (imgName.at(0))[0]; // result is n
```